# Cannot store radio button value in table

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am trying to save the value of the radio buttons in my database table `choice`. I get the message `Data saved successfully` but no value is stored in the table.

Form:

```
   <form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
<div  data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <center<legend>Choose in which category you'd like to be included</legend></center>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="player" id="player" class="custom" />
                    <label for="player">Player</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="coach" id="coach" class="custom" />
                    <label for="coach">Coach</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="supporter" id="supporter" class="custom" />
                    <label for="supporter">Supporter</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="sponsor" id="sponsor" class="custom" />
                    <label for="sponsor">Sponsor</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="alumni" id="alumni" class="custom" />
                    <label for="alumni">Alumni</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice[]" value="other" id="o" class="custom" />
                    <label for="o">Other</label>

                </fieldset>
            </div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Please enter your name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" value="" autocomplete="off" /><br />
    <label for="email">Please enter your e-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required" autocomplete="off"  /><br />
    <label for="phone">Please enter your phone number:</label>
    <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="required" autocomplete="off"  />

<br><br>    
<label for="other">Other comments</label>
<textarea name="other" id="other" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Anything else you'd like to add?">
</textarea>
<p><strong id="error"></strong></p>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Submit Form" />
<p id="response"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'E-mail list');
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$other = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['other']);
$choice = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['choice']);
$query = "INSERT INTO Players (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`other`,`choice`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$other."','".$choice."')";
if($mysqli->query($query))
{
echo 'Data Saved Successfully.';
}
else
{
echo 'Cannot save data.';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the mysql data type for choice?  Also, please echo the $query in your file and let us know the results printed to the screen.  Helpful to see what value, if any, choice is getting.  It is obviously getting the right value of save for that part to execute.

Comment: I did an echo on $query and it shows no value for choice.

Comment: something else is going on here or there is more code that is somewhere else in your script that is overwriting or making a difference.  I ran the simple code on my server and didn't have any issue.  Your form is submitting via post.  Maybe provide more of your code regarding to the form.  Try echoing the value of choice via POST higher in your code to see the value of choice there.

Comment: Please show us your whole `form` html markup.

Comment: thanks for all the replies. i have now added the whole form!

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump($_POST)` to sere what data flooding in.

One thing more  to check if its save or submit ? in `$_POST['save']`

**EDIT**

After getting your full form - the error lies in your `center` tag

Change `<center<legend>` TO `<center><legend>`

The error -  ↑  in this tag

Comment: Thanks! I get this message: 
{ ["name"]=> string(1) "q" ["email"]=> string(1) "q" ["phone"]=> string(1) "q" ["other"]=> string(1) "q" ["save"]=> string(11) "Submit Form" }

Comment: it seems like there is no value for choice. i am clueless

Comment: @PAHemingstam can you please add more html form data..check if all ids are unique and yes they have values also

Comment: @PAHemingstam Got the solution..if u pasted it early u wont have to wait for such a long time :)  Added this in my answer

Comment: That is not the solution unfortunately :(. All values are saved except the one for 'choice'